# How do I compare two longs as unsigned in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, math

I'm storing bit patterns of unsigned 64-bit numbers in a `long` variable and want to calculate the distance between two of them on the unsigned range. Because Java interprets `long` as a two's complement signed integer, I can't just do `a - b`, as the following example shows:

```
// on the unsigned range, these numbers would be adjacent
long a = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
long b = 0x8000000000000000L;

// but as two's complement (or any representation that 
// stores the sign in the first bit), they aren't
assert b - a == 1;
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: As noted by several posters below, my example does, in fact, work. I extracted it from more complex code in my application without testing it afterwards and later found out that I had another error in that original code which led me to believe that the binary representation was the problem. This means the question does not make a lot of sense anymore. However, the answers were very helpful to me so I just leave this up as it is.

Comment: I think I remember there being an answer that was showing in binary how I can use the calculated difference later to retrieve b by `b = a + d`, and why for that purpose it doesn't matter how you would interpret the bit pattern. But that answer is either gone or I saw it somewhere else. Still, it helped. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dealing with addition and subtraction, it doesn't matter whether you're using signed or unsigned types, as long as the arguments are both signed or both unsigned.  If you need to compare a and b, compare a-b to 0.

Comment: Adding and subtracting is really the only thing I need. I store the delta to later reconstruct the original value from it.

Comment: @Adam *If you need to compare a and b, compare a-b to 0* - I don't think that works. For simplicity consider unsigned `byte` comparison between `a=0x80` and `b=0x7F`. In signed terms `a = -128` and `b = 127`. Now `a-b > 0` should be `true` if they are unsigned, but it is not in Java as the type `byte` is signed.

Comment: @Aravind The byte example doesn't work because in Java, bytes get upcast to ints before performing arithmetic.  In that case, you'd use (byte)(a-b), which for a=0x80 and b=0x7f would yield 1.

Comment: I don't get you. If a is a small magnitude positive, and b is a slightly larger magnitude negative, then a - b > 0 gives an affirmative answer, which is correct if you're treating the inputs as signed. However if we consider them both unsigned, then b is actually a large positive, and a - b > 0 should be false.

Comment: @AdamCrume Your answer is partially correct - only if you check a and b for equality. The common comparison case is much more complex, like some answers below show

Answer (score 8):

Starting with **Java 8**, the comparison of `long` as unsigned integers can be done via [Long.compareUnsigned(x, y)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-).

Here is a simple backport for Java 7 and earlier:

```
public static int compareUnsigned(long x, long y) {
   return Long.compare(x + Long.MIN_VALUE, y + Long.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As the arithmetic wraps round, it works out the same for the case you give. If you interpret the result as an unsigned value, it will be true for all cases - you're just changing the interpretation of the bit pattern, it's still a set homomorphic to ***Ζ**2<sup>64</sup>*.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
long a = 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
long b = 0x8000000000000000L;
b - a = (long) 1
a - b = (long) -1
```

Comment: Totally correct, I had a bug in the code I extracted the example from. See my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution:

```
if (longA == longB) return 0;
return (longA < longB) ^ (longA < 0) ^ (longB< 0) ? 1 : -1;
```

[All credits go to this website](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/08/unsigned-comparison-in-javascala/)

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, you won't have a problem with subtraction, so if that is all you are trying to do, then don't worry.

But, by your example, addition will overflow, and none of the relational operators will work properly. If this is a concern then you can write your own relational ops, or use a better box type than Long.

Solutions:
1. Use BigInteger instead of Long. [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) was created for doing calculations with large numbers and can easily support 128bit calculations.

2. Write your own relational operations and exclude the used of addition or multiplication as a possibility. Writing your own relational operator is really not that hard. First you compare the most significant bit. If the most significant bit is the same for both numbers, you can mask it by doing a bitwise and (&) with 0X7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and then compare the masked values.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code:

```
static boolean unsignedLessThan(long left, long right) { 
    return (left < right) ^ (left < 0) ^ (right < 0);
}
```

(based on example by Tamutnefret)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html

Comment: The workaround that darksleep offers is to cast the signed type to a type that uses twice as many bytes, e.g. use a short (2 bytes) to hold an unsigned byte, or an int (4 bytes) to hold an unsigned short. However, Java doesn't have a built-in 16-byte numeric type that the OP could use to store unsigned longs (8 bytes) in.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need deal with bits.

```
static boolean compare(long a, long b)
{
    if(( a &  (Long.MAX_VALUE + 1)) != 0)
        return ( b & (Long.MAX_VALUE + 1) )  != 0
            ? (a < b) //same sign 
            : true; //a is greater b
    else 
        return ( b & (Long.MAX_VALUE + 1) )  != 0
            ? false //b is greater a
            : a < b; //same sign
}
```

Comment: It is enough to map unsigned space [0,2^64-1] to signed one [2^63,2^63-1] before the comparision

`static boolean compare(long a, long b) {
  return a^0x8000000000000000L < b^0x8000000000000000L;
}
`


`Long.compare(a^0x8000000000000000L, b^0x8000000000000000L)
`

would also work

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do half and half like this,

```
public static long unsignedDiff(long a, long b) {
    long mask = 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    return (( ((a >> 32) & mask) - ((b >> 32) & mask) ) << 32) +
       + ((a & mask) - (b & mask));
}
```